# Lua Accessing a table's Keys and Values

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I would like to read a Lua file in a level editor so I can display its data in visual format for users to edit.

If I have a Lua table like so:

```
properties = {
  Speed = 10,
  TurnSpeed = 5
}
```

`Speed` is obviously the key and `10` the value. I know I can access the value if I know the key like so (provided the table is already on the stack):

```
lua_pushstring(L, "Speed");
lua_gettable(L, idx); 
int Speed = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

What I want to do is access the key's name and the corresponding value, in C++. Can this be done? If so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered by the [`lua_next` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next), which iterates over the elements of a table:

```
// table is in the stack at index 't'
lua_pushnil(L);  // first key
while (lua_next(L, t) != 0)
{
  // uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1)
  printf("%s - %s\n", luaL_typename(L, -2), luaL_typename(L, -1));
  // removes 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration
  lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

`lua_next` keys off of the, um, key of the table, so you need to keep that on the stack while you're iterating. Each call will jump to the next key/value pair. Once it returns 0, then you're done (and while the key was popped, the next wasn't pushed).

Obviously adding or removing elements to a table you're iterating over can cause issues.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the key for the next iteration?

Comment: The key is popped by `lua_next()`, which then puts the next key/value pair onto the stack (it has to identify the "next" element after all as `t` is just the table, not the current index).

Comment: @DavidC: Because if you don't, `lua_next` doesn't work. It's not magic, after all; it needs some way to know what "next" means. It uses the key for that. You start with a "key" of `nil`, which tells `lua_next` to get the "first" key. It then uses the current key to decide where the next one is. It's no different from the index in a loop over an array, or in C++, an iterator.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I was looking all over for why `lua_pushnil` is needed.  Your comment clears it up for me.  Thanks!