# Is there any Lua table iterator wrapper for C++?

Tags: c++, lua, iterator, lua-table

I want to call some C++ function from Lua code and pass Lua table in parameters, something like this:

```
call_cpp_function_from_lua({ x = 10, y = 20 })
```

In `call_cpp_function_from_lua` I would like to get and use iterator for C++ representation of Lua table, something like this:

```
std::map<boost::variant<LuaTypesList>, boost::variant<LuaTypesList>>::iterator it = getLuaTableBegin();
```

I can use C API to do it but it is tedious an error prone, see [Iterating through a Lua table from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1438842/72178).

Comment: You can see different examples of using iterator in http://lua-users.org/wiki/IteratorsTutorial

Comment: @user1929959: He means ***C++ iterators***, not Lua iterators.

Comment: "*but it is tedious an error prone*" You're going to have to write that code one way or another. Unless you're asking for a library. The only thing a C++ iterator does for you is wrap it in a specific interface; the implementation of that interface is the hard part.

Comment: Luabind can do that. I'm not sure if it's a real answer though, the original maintainers have decided not to go on with the project for some time already, so e.g. you may need to patch it in some configurations (GCC + a recent version of Boost IIRC). And it provides a bit more than just marshalling data to and from Lua.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Yes, I am asking about library with C++ iterator interface, which could hide details of iterating in Lua C API.

Answer (score 1):

[QtLua library](http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/manual/Iterator_class_reference.html) implements C++ iterators for Lua tables. It has `Value::iterator` and `Value::const_iterator` classes, allowing iteration of Lua tables. Here is a short example on how to use them:

```
// code from examples/cpp/value/iterate.cc:32

    QtLua::State state;

    // New lua table value
    state.exec_statements("table = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }");

    QtLua::Value table = state["table"];

    // Iterate over lua table from C++ code
    for (QtLua::Value::const_iterator i = table.begin(); i != table.end(); i++)
      qDebug() << i.key().to_string_p()
               << i.value().to_string_p();
```