# Loop through all Lua global variables in C++

Tags: c++, lua, global-variables, lua-5.2

I have been searching for quite a while now and I haven't found a way to fetch all the global variables from C++. Consider this small Lua test script.

```
myGlobal1 = "Global 1"
myGlobal2 = 2

function test()
  local l1=0
  print (myGlobal1,myGlobal2,l1)
end

test()
```

Assume you pause the execution at `print (myGlobal1,myGlobal2,l1)` and from C++ get all the global variables (`myGlobal1` and `myGlobal2`). These examples are arbitrary, the global variables, from a C++ point of view, are unknown.

I have been looking at `lua_getglobal()` but then I need to know the name of the variable first. I looked at `lua_getupvalue()` but only got "`_ENV`" as result.

I guess I can use `lua_getglobal()` as soon I know the name of them, but how do I get the list of global variables (from C++)? I do have the `lua_Debug` structure at this point (if it is to any help)

**EDIT**
This post wasn't originally about iterating through a table, it was about how to find the user's own globals.

However, I posted a solution to how this can be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527659/how-to-filter-out-user-defined-globals-in-lua-from-c).

Comment: [Use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438842/iterating-through-a-lua-table-from-c) remembering that globals are just indexes in `_G`.

Comment: @Bartek So iterating through _G will give me all global variables?

Comment: @Tadeusz It is Lua5.2, as the tag shows ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay I solved it.

```
lua_pushglobaltable(L);       // Get global table
lua_pushnil(L);               // put a nil key on stack
while (lua_next(L,-2) != 0) { // key(-1) is replaced by the next key(-1) in table(-2)
  name = lua_tostring(L,-2);  // Get key(-2) name
  lua_pop(L,1);               // remove value(-1), now key on top at(-1)
}
lua_pop(L,1);                 // remove global table(-1)
```

When `lua_next()` can't find more entries the key name is popped leaving the table on top(-1).

Next problem would be to distinguish my own globals from the rest of the table entries...

Comment: The [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_next) says: "While traversing a table, do not call `lua_tolstring` directly on a key, unless you know that the key is actually a string. Recall that `lua_tolstring` may change the value at the given index; this confuses the next call to `lua_next`.". It is unlikely that you'd have a global variable whose name is not a string but it may happen.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I forgot to edit my post about it. I'm trying to find a better way to filter out my globals.

Comment: Ask a separate question about filtering out your globals.

Comment: @lhf Yes I posted a new question ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527659/how-to-filter-out-user-defined-globals-in-lua-from-c

Comment: @MaxKielland: thanks for posting this.  I was experimenting with an answer and got crashes because I was passing `-1` as the index of the table to `lua_next()`. The doc for `lua_next()` (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_next) has an example of walking a table, but only says that "table is in the stack at index 't'". At the point of the comment the table's stack index is `-1` - so that's what I tried.  For some reason it never clicked for me that I should try `-2`, which in retrospect seems like should have been an obvious thing to try.

Comment: @MichaelBurr a week ago I didn't even know that Lua existed :) Yes, I have also found some documentation a bit sparse and I have done quite some trial and error cases, but I start to get some understanding of how it works now... :) I have to send many thanks to lhf for his help and patience...