# Simple lua example of passing a table to c/c++

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table

I am struggling finding and understanding how to pass a table from lua to c++

What I have:

Lua File:

```
-- lua script for sending table data
io.write("lua table to send")
tableexample = {x = 1, y = 2, z = 100}
return tableexample
```

c/c++ side

```
L = lua_open();
luaL_openfile(L, "luafile");
... call the function...
luaLdofile(L, luafile);
int result;
result = lua_pcall(L,0, LUA_MULTRET,0);
if(result){
fprintf(stderr, "failed %s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));

if(lua_istable(L,-1)){
  lua_gettable(L,-1);
  x = lua_tonumber(L,-2);
  y = lua_tonumber(L,-3);
  z = lua_tonumber(L,-4);
}
else
printf("fail");
```

the result comes back with a failure "attempt to call a table value"

I've looked at many different tutorials/examples but haven't found a simple tutorial that doesn't have 100 other things going on and am getting myself confused

some references that are similar - but too complex for what I am looking for
[Iterating through a Lua table from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438842/iterating-through-a-lua-table-from-c)

Comment: So what language are  you using, C or C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `lua_gettable` is wrong.

Have a look at the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_gettable):

> `void lua_gettable (lua_State *L, int index);`
>
> Pushes onto the stack the value `t[k]`, where `t` is the value at the
>   given index and `k` is the value at the top of the stack.
>
> This function pops the key from the stack (putting the resulting value
>   in its place).

In your example, the value at the top of the stack is the table itself, so you are doing the equivalent of a `tableexample[tableexample]` lookup.

The shortest way to achieve what you want is to use [`lua_getfield`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getfield) instead, which allows accessing table elements by string keys:

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "x");
```

Alternatively, push a Lua value of type string on the stack first and use `lua_gettable` for the lookup.

```
lua_pushliteral(L, "x");
lua_gettable(L, -2);
```

Don't forget to keep your stack balanced. Every value that you push on the stack needs to be popped properly. The Lua manual specifies how each API call changes the stack by the numbers in the [`\[ \]` brackets on the right side of each function name](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.8).

Comment: its failing on the lua_pcall though - so I don't even make it to the lua_istable

Comment: @morty346 You probably did not initialize the `io` library then. Remove the line with the `io.write` for a quick fix, or do some [research](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_requiref) on how to get the standard libraries initialized.

Comment: but like I said the error is "attempt to call a table value" - so not an IO fail (also I removed the io.write and did not change the error code)

Comment: @morty346 Sorry, my bad, I overlooked the `luaLdofile` line. That line already executed the code and created the table, so you don't need the pcall below that. pcall will attempt to call the function on the top of the stack, which, in your case, is the `tableexample`, hence the error message. Just remove the pcall and you should be fine.

Comment: That did the trick (as did your exaplanation to the actual problem as well