# Get Array return from Lua using C++

Tags: c++, binding, lua

I have a Lua script like this.

```
function add(x,y)

   return {x,x/2.0,y,y*y,x*y,x+y}

end
```

How can I get the return array from c/c++ code?

Comment: Can you show your C++ code?

Comment: I get it done referencing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438842/iterating-through-a-lua-table-from-c